# Call function of page from service in ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I know I can call functions from my page module to my service. However how can I call a function from my service TO my page module?

I tried importing the page into my service

```
import { MainPage } from '../../pages/game/main/main.page';
```

and then calling the function `this.mainService.init();`

however i am getting an error of

```
Circular dependency detected
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the service:

```
  private mySubject = new Subject<any>();
  ob = this.mySubject.asObservable();

  serviceFn(value:any) {
    this.mySubject.next(value);
  }
```

In the component:

```
constructor(private myService:MyService){}
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.myService.ob.subscribe((result) => {
          this.foo(result);
        }
      );
  }

  foo(result:any)
  {
    //access result here
  }
```

Now whenever you call myService.serviceFn(argValue), function foo() in the component will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

your service include in `provider` array in module like `app.module.ts` or `page.module.ts` then after call `this.mainService.init()` function in service file `constructor`

if service instance is create then your init function is called

**app.module.ts** or **page.module.ts**

```
  providers: [
        ...
        YourService
      ],
```

Comment: The issue is i'm also injecting the service into my page.